# read fucntion in C uint_8 and char array buffer differences

Tags: c

in some code seen online, i saw that in read function in C, someone uses a **uint8_t** array for buffer insted of a **char** array buffer.
what are the differences?
thanks

Comment: Historical. `uint8_t` is a relatively recent addition to the language.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so there aren't differences?

Comment: More often than not it makes no sense. Use `unsigned char` buffers for IO. Use `uint8_t` for 8-bit arithmetic.

Comment: `char` and `uint8_t` are different types as seen by `_Generic`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In all implementations `char, signed char, unsigned char` are all different types. `uint8_t` follows "The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type", so I do not see `uint8_t` as the same type as `char` even in an implementation where 8-bit `char` is _unsigned_ as being compliant.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Agreed.

Comment: The POSIX specification for `read()` uses `void*`, not `char*` or `unit8_t*`. Where did you see something else?

Comment: @Barmar: The question does not say somebody uses a `char *` or `uint8_t *` parameter declaration in a declaration of `read`. It says they use a `char` array or `uint8_t` array with `read`, which is perfectly natural and works with the standard declaration of `read`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ["Oh, that's different. Never mind."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Litella)

Answer (score 5):

The C standard allows `char` to be signed or unsigned. It also allows it to be more than eight bits.

`uint8_t`, if it is defined, is unsigned and eight bits. This allows programmers to be completely sure of the type that will be used. In particular, signed `char` types sometimes cause problems with bitwise and shift operations, due to how these operations are defined (or are not defined) when negative values are involved.

Comment: thanks, so for a simple use like in a buffer, there aren't significant differences?

Comment: @ServerSocket: It is easy for an array of `char` to go awry. For example, `isapha(buffer[0])` is not defined by the C standard if `buffer[0]` is negative (and not equal to `EOF`). Generally, you should prefer `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` until you know C well enough to write a good argument that the code is correct with `char`.

Comment: Correction: `isapha` → `isalpha`, as declared in `<ctype.h>`

Comment: In a platform where `char` has more than 8 bits, `uint8_t` either does not exist or has padding bits, which will probably break your code. Most C code that has binary IO will break on such a platform anyway, `uint8_t` or not.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. `uint8_t` cannot have padding. "The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N and no padding bits."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah so it doesn't exist then.

Answer (score 0):

So every char corresponds to a number(see ascii table [here](https://www.asciitable.com)). I think people use this to avoid some problems(sorry I don't use c I come from c++)